# Join sql performance consideration

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

So i have three tables with column:

```
merchant:
-id
-name

store:
-id
-merchantId
-name

transaction
-id
-merchantId
-storeId
```

i want to ask, which is better performance to get merchant detail, first we remove merchantId on transaction table and perform join query with storeId then join merchantId or we don't remove merchantId and perform join query to each table based on storeId and merchantId on transaction table?

we assume store and transaction have a lot of data

Comment: If the columns you join on are indexed, performance should be reasonable. Since ID should be the primary key, it will automatically be indexed. And if you declare `merchantId` and `storeId` as foreign keys, they'll be indexed.

Comment: Show us the code for each way; we can discuss pros and cons of the two approaches.  (What you have it too vague.)

Answer (score 1):

In here you used normalization for the data and it's fine that you have three tables but going for more normalization means it will take a performance hit when receiving data. So what you can do here is use ***pagination***. To use pagination in MySQL you can use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`keywords. You can use below ways,

```
SELECT
 merchant.name,
 store.name,
 transaction.storeID
FROM merchant
JOIN store
ON merchant.id = store.merchantId
JOIN transaction
ON transaction.storeId= store.id ORDER by merchant.id asc LIMIT 100;
```

Here you will get 1-100 values.

```
SELECT
 merchant.name,
 store.name,
 transaction.storeID
FROM merchant
JOIN store
ON merchant.id = store.merchantId
JOIN transaction
ON transaction.storeId= store.id ORDER by merchant.id asc LIMIT 100 OFFSET 20;
```

Here you will get 21-120 values

Comment: LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing rarely makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out missed that while formatting

Answer (score 0):

The Transaction table should not include the merchantId column. A data model should not permit multiple paths between two objects

Comment: Multiple relationships between tables are perfectly normal and can yield different sets of rows.

Comment: Fair point, assuming you aren't trying to create a model in 3NF I guess

Answer (score 0):

Using a 2-step process is almost always 'worse':

```
Query 1:
SELECT id ...  --> into an array
Query 2:
... WHERE id IN (...)   --> using that list of ids
```

It is better to do some kind of `JOIN` or `EXISTS` to combine them into a single query.  And it is likely to be almost twice as fast.

`INDEXes` are vital to performance.  But indexes should be designed based on the queries (especially `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`) that you will be performing.  (That is, don't simply "index every column".)

Finding a single row in a suitably indexed million-row table is almost as fast as in a hundred-row table.